# Http PUT method in flask is failing in assertion

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, rest, flask

Hi Healthy Programmers,

I had been attending a lot of hands-on lately. I Had been studying Flask programming and trying various samples found in online programming platforms and challenges. I am stuck at one solution wherein i was able to clear 7 test cases and one is failing for a very long time now. I am unable to view or set my mind outside of this solution that i had written.

Can someone be kind enough to help me in cracking this PUT http test case please. I have attached the test case and also my source code herewith.

#### blogs_app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, abort

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


blogs = {}

class BlogsAPI(Resource):
    def get(self, blog_id=None):
      if blog_id is None:
            return blogs
      if blog_id not in blogs:
          abort(404,message="Blog_Id {} doesn't exist".format(blog_id))
      return blogs[blog_id]

def post(self, blog_id):
  if blog_id not in blogs:
        title = request.form['title']
        article_text = request.form['article_text']
        created_at = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        blogs[blog_id] = {'title': title, 'article_text':article_text, 'created_at':created_at}
        return {blog_id: blogs[blog_id]}
  abort(404, message='Blog_Id {} already exists'.format(blog_id))

def put(self, blog_id):
  if blog_id not in blogs:
    abort(404,message="Blog_Id {} doesn't exist".format(blog_id))
  blogs[blog_id] = request.form['title']
  return {blog_id: blogs[blog_id]}

def delete(self, blog_id):
  if blog_id in blogs:
    response_string = 'Blog with Id {} is deleted'.format(blog_id)
    del blogs[blog_id]
    return response_string
  abort(404, message="Blog_Id {} doesn't exist".format(blog_id))

api.add_resource(BlogsAPI, '/blogs/',
                              '/blogs/<int:blog_id>/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This is the Test case file that was provided.

#### test_app.py

```
from blogs_app import app
import unittest
from urllib import request
import datetime

class TestBlogsAPI(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = app.test_client()

    def test_blogs_api_case1(self):
        blog = {'title' : 'Python Application Programming',
                'article_text': 'This article talks about Python and illustrates how Python is used in application programming, with examples.',
                }
        response = self.client.post('/blogs/1/', data=blog)
        self.assertIn(b'"title": "Python Application Programming"', response.data)
        self.assertIn(b'"article_text": "This article talks about Python and illustrates how Python is used in application programming, with examples."', response.data)
        
        
    def test_blogs_api_case2(self):
        blog = {'title' : 'Flask - A Micro Web Framework in Python',
                'article_text': 'This article talks about Flask framework. It can be used to build web apps in a quick time.',
                }
        response = self.client.post('/blogs/2/', data=blog)
        self.assertIn(b'"title": "Flask - A Micro Web Framework in Python"', response.data)
        self.assertIn(b'"article_text": "This article talks about Flask framework. It can be used to build web apps in a quick time."', response.data)
        
    def test_blogs_api_case3(self):
        blog = {'title' : 'Flask-RESTful - Flask Extension for building REST APIs',
                'article_text': 'This article introduces you to Flask-RESTful, an extension used for building REST APIs in Flask.',
                }
        response = self.client.post('/blogs/3/', data=blog)
        self.assertIn(b'"title": "Flask-RESTful - Flask Extension for building REST APIs"', response.data)
        self.assertIn(b'"article_text": "This article introduces you to Flask-RESTful, an extension used for building REST APIs in Flask."', response.data)
        
    def test_blogs_api_case4(self):
        response = self.client.get('/blogs/')
        self.assertIn(b'"title": "Python Application Programming"', response.data)
        self.assertIn(b'"article_text": "This article talks about Python and illustrates how Python is used in application programming, with examples."', response.data)
        self.assertIn(b'"title": "Flask - A Micro Web Framework in Python"', response.data)
        self.assertIn(b'"article_text": "This article talks about Flask framework. It can be used to build web apps in a quick time."', response.data)
        self.assertIn(b'"title": "Flask-RESTful - Flask Extension for building REST APIs"', response.data)
        self.assertIn(b'"article_text": "This article introduces you to Flask-RESTful, an extension used for building REST APIs in Flask."', response.data)
        
    def test_blogs_api_case5(self):
        response = self.client.get('/blogs/3/')
        self.assertNotIn(b'"title": "Python Application Programming"', response.data)
        self.assertNotIn(b'"article_text": "This article talks about Python and illustrates how Python is used in application programming, with examples."', response.data)
        self.assertNotIn(b'"title": "Flask - A Micro Web Framework in Python"', response.data)
        self.assertNotIn(b'"article_text": "This article talks about Flask framework. It can be used to build web apps in a quick time."', response.data)
        self.assertIn(b'"title": "Flask-RESTful - Flask Extension for building REST APIs"', response.data)
        self.assertIn(b'"article_text": "This article introduces you to Flask-RESTful, an extension used for building REST APIs in Flask."', response.data)
    
        
    def test_blogs_api_case5(self):
        response = self.client.delete('/blogs/3/')
        self.assertIn(b'Blog with Id 3 is deleted', response.data)
        response = self.client.get('/blogs/')
        self.assertIn(b'"title": "Python Application Programming"', response.data)
        self.assertIn(b'"article_text": "This article talks about Python and illustrates how Python is used in application programming, with examples."', response.data)
        self.assertIn(b'"title": "Flask - A Micro Web Framework in Python"', response.data)
        self.assertIn(b'"article_text": "This article talks about Flask framework. It can be used to build web apps in a quick time."', response.data)
        self.assertNotIn(b'"title": "Flask-RESTful - Flask Extension for building REST APIs"', response.data)
        self.assertNotIn(b'"article_text": "This article introduces you to Flask-RESTful, an extension used for building REST APIs in Flask."', response.data)
        
    def test_blogs_api_case6(self):
        response = self.client.delete('/blogs/6/')
        self.assertIn(b"Blog_Id 6 doesn't exist", response.data)
        
    def test_blogs_api_case7(self):
        blog = {'title' : 'PYTHON APPLICATION PROGRAMMING',
                }
        response = self.client.put('/blogs/7/', data=blog)

        self.assertIn(b"Blog_Id 7 doesn't exist", response.data)
        
    def test_blogs_api_case8(self):
        blog = {'title' : 'PYTHON APPLICATION PROGRAMMING'}
        response = self.client.put('/blogs/1/', data=blog)
        
        self.assertIn(b'"title": "PYTHON APPLICATION PROGRAMMING"', response.data)
        self.assertIn(b'"article_text": "This article talks about Python and illustrates how Python is used in application programming, with examples."', response.data)
```

I am getting the below error message upon running and the 8th test case fails :(

```
test_blogs_api_case1 (test_app.TestBlogsAPI) ... ok
test_blogs_api_case2 (test_app.TestBlogsAPI) ... ok
test_blogs_api_case3 (test_app.TestBlogsAPI) ... ok
test_blogs_api_case4 (test_app.TestBlogsAPI) ... ok
test_blogs_api_case5 (test_app.TestBlogsAPI) ... ok
test_blogs_api_case6 (test_app.TestBlogsAPI) ... ok
test_blogs_api_case7 (test_app.TestBlogsAPI) ... ok
test_blogs_api_case8 (test_app.TestBlogsAPI) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_blogs_api_case8 (test_app.TestBlogsAPI)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projects/challenge/test_app.py", line 81, in test_blogs_api_case8
    self.assertIn(b'"article_text": "This article talks about Python and illustrates how Python is used in application programming, with examples."', response.data)
AssertionError: b'"article_text": "This article talks about Python and illustrates how Python is used in application programming, with examples."' not found in b'{"1": {"title": "PYTHON APPLICATION PROGRAMMING"}}\n'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 8 tests in 0.022s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: Can you show us what `response.data` is?

Comment: @waqasgard The response data is in the form of a dictionary object "Blogs"

**Eg:** 

`b'{"Python Application Programming": "This article talks about Python and illustrates how Python is used in application programming, with examples."}\n' `

Comment: Can you confirm that the response actually has what you're trying to assert?

Comment: @waqasgard: yes i confirm its available.. b'{"PYTHON APPLICATION PROGRAMMING": "This article talks about Python and illustrates how Python is used in application programming, with examples."}\n' 


Not sure why the PUT method is not getting asserted even when the the response is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
def put(self, blog_id):
  if blog_id not in blogs:
    abort(404,message="Blog_Id {} doesn't exist".format(blog_id))
  **blogs[blog_id]['title'] = request.form['title']**
  return {blog_id: blogs[blog_id]}
```

change the put method

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def put(self, blog_id):
        if blog_id not in blogs:
            abort(404, message="Blog_Id {} doesn't exist".format(blog_id))
        blogs[blog_id]['title'] = request.form['title']
        return blogs[blog_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

> the main problem was of this problem that the updated 'key' was not
> given, so we have to check test cases first, As per test cases the
> updated key was 'title' so we have to updates this key value by using
> an HTTP request.

```
def put(self, blog_id):
     if blog_id not in blogs:
        abort(404,message="Blog_Id {} doesn't exist".format(blog_id))
     blogs[blog_id]['title'] = request.form['title']
     return {blog_id: blogs[blog_id]}
```